# NIH class tweaks

Tags: header-footer, margins, document-classes

I need to change a few settings from the [NIH document-class](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nih/nih.cls) to make my document more similar to NIH's most recent [sample](http://www.niaid.nih.gov/researchfunding/grant/documents/parrishresplan.pdf) (ugly, I know). Having been told to leave the .cls file well alone, I'm going to incorporate the changes into my document. Here's what I need to do:

1. Put the header and footer outside the 0.5-inch margin, as in the sample. This I accomplished by adding the following line:

   ```
    \geometry{ignoreheadfoot}
   ```
2. That command unfortunately puts the header and footer right up against the paper's edges, possibly outside the printable area. How do I add a small margin in case I have to bring the two within printable area without affecting the body's 0.5-inch margin.
3. Unlike the script-size central header, the right header (PI name) currently has a normal size, which bleeds off the paper when `ignoreheadfoot` is set. If I copy the entire `\rhead` chunk from the .cls file to the document in order to modify it, I get an error. Why is that? (This is not the case with the `\chead` chunk, which copied and pasted and edited without incident.)
4. What does the `\fancyplain` and `\ifthenelse` in the .cls file do anyway (example below)? Question 3 would be trivial if I could just set my own `\rhead` without regard to what the class file is trying to do.

   ```
   \rhead{\fancyplain{}{%
   \ifthenelse{\boolean{nih@blank}}%
       {\ \ \ {\nih@PIname}\ \ \ \ \ }% fi
       {%
           \underline{\ \ \ {\nih@PIname}\ \ \ \ \ }%
       }% esle
    }
    }
   ```

And here's a minimal representation of my document. Many thanks.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{nih}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{ignoreheadfoot}
\piname{Holmes, Sherlock}

\begin{document}
\section*{Specific Aims}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: This question never got any action. Are you still interested in this matter or can we close this?

Comment: One issue at a time please: as it stands too broad.